# wso2 am google analitycs integration doesn't work

Tags: google-analytics, wso2-api-manager

I have a WSO2 Api manager 1.9.0 installation. I configured the integration with GA as it is described in https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM190/Integrating+with+Google+Analytics

I have registered a simple API (http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx) and created a soapui load test to do a hundred of calls to the API.

I can see the calls in the wso2carbon.log but the calls are not tracked in google analytics. Any idea why?

ciao & thanks
Alberto

Comment: Any error in apim logs..